# How can I get first element of HTML Collection?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that returns 1 element inside of a HTML Collection:

```
var message = document.getElementsByClassName('short-description shipp-info'); //Returns collection with 1 div element, which is what I want

//Returned value from message;
    HTMLCollection []
    0: div.short-description.shipp-info
    length: 1
    __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

However, when I try and get the first element, it returns undefined:

```
    var message = document.getElementsByClassName('short-description shipp-info')[0]; //Returns undefined
     //or
    message[0]; //Returns undefined
```

This is how I have always retrieved the first element from HTML Collections and it's always worked until now. I have no idea why it's not working. There are also no errors being reported in the console, other than this being undefined.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I've done it that way before, and it is returning the element I want, as I stated above. It's just not returning when I want the one specific element.

Comment: We are going to need to see an example how it fails. My guess is you are trying to find the element before it exists....

Comment: Turns out @epascarello is correct, the element wasn't loaded yet. I wrapped it in a window.onload function and the element is showing up now. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName is a live HTML Collection. So it will add and subtract elements as they are added and removed from the page. So if you add an element, it appears in your collection. Example below

```js
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
console.log("before", test.length);
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.className = "foo";
document.body.appendChild(d)
console.log("after add", test.length);
d.className = "bar";
console.log("after remove class", test.length);
```

So what is probably happening is you are trying to reference the element before it is on the page. When you log, you are probably seeing the browsers lazy loading where is shows you the data at the current point in time, not when it was added.